# use of texture arrays with freetype in opengl

Tags: opengl, textures, freetype

After having read and run the following tutorial (http://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=in-practice/text_rendering), I learned how to render text using freetype in OpenGL. I am now wondering if it is possible to avoid calling glDrawArrays for each glyph. Hence I have done some modifications on the VBO to use it for whole string instead of one glyph.  As a first step I have used the string "AA" and since both glyphs are identical, they also share the same texture. So it was not an issue to get the following code running:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, & textVAO);
glBindVertexArray(textVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &textVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,textVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24* 2* sizeof(float), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer( 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
```

followed by:

```
textShader.Use();
glm::vec3 color;
color = glm::vec3(1.0, 0.7f, 0.9f);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(textShader.Program, "textColor"), color.x, color.y, color.z);
glBindVertexArray(textVAO);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
int k=0;
for(c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++){
    Character ch = Characters[*c];
    GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
    GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;
    GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
    GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
    V.block(0,k,24,1) << xpos, ypos + h,0.0,0.0,xpos, ypos,0.0,1.0,xpos + w, ypos,1.0,1.0,xpos, ypos + h,0.0,0.0,xpos + w,ypos,1.0,1.0,xpos + w, ypos+h,1.0,0.0;
    k++;
    x += ( (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale);
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,66);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,textVBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 24* 2* sizeof(float), V.data());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,4*3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
```

I would like to be able to render "AB" or "ZW" on the screen so I am now trying to use a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY together with glTexImage3D and glTexSubImage3D. Again for simplification I use "AA" in order to have the same width and height for the glyphs. So I added

```
GLuint textureArray;
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
glGenTextures(1, &textureArray);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureArray);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 4, 30, 35, 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

to the first part of the precedent code and the second part has become:

```
textShader.Use();
glm::vec3 color;
color = glm::vec3(1.0, 0.7f, 0.9f);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(textShader.Program, "textColor"), color.x, color.y, color.z);
glBindVertexArray(textVAO);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
for(c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++) {
    Character ch = Characters[*c];
    GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
    GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;
    GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
    GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
    V.block(0,k,24,1) << xpos, ypos + h,0.0,0.0,xpos, ypos,0.0,1.0,xpos + w, ypos,1.0,1.0,xpos, ypos + h,0.0,0.0,xpos + w,ypos,1.0,1.0,xpos + w, ypos+h,1.0,0.0;
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, k, 30,35, 1, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ch.pointeur);
    k++;
    x += ( (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale);
    }
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,textureArray);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,textVBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 24* 2* sizeof(float), V.data());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,4*3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
```

The code compiles, but I don't get anything on the screen. So I wonder if I am using correctly the GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY and also if I have to do an "array version" of the shaders. I am using OpenGL 4.5, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems.

First, you are using the fixed-function pipeline, which *cannot* be used with array textures. The texture environment accessing stuff does not know how to handle them. If you want to use array textures, you *must* use shaders.

Second, even if you were using shaders, you are doing this all wrong. Then again, you were taught wrongly by the tutorial (which in this case is teaching such bad practice that it's actively damaging to OpenGL users). You put each glyph in its own array layer. Well, many OpenGL implementations [only support 256 array layers](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_stats_caps_single.php?listreportsbycap=GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS), which is not a lot of glyphs if you want to include non-English text.

The correct way to do glyph rendering is to build a texture atlas of glyphs, rather than using a glyph-per-texture (as the crappy tutorial does) or a glyph-per-array-layer (as you do). You put multiple glyphs in different locations of a single 2D texture, then use texture coordinates to pick which glyph to use. That will allow you to submit entire blocks of text with a single draw call.

2D texture sizes can be upwards of 16K in pixels these days. Even with only 4096x4096 textures, you can fit over 16 *thousand* 32x32 glyphs into them.

Comment: As the author of the tutorial I'd like to shed a bit of insight: I agree that packing all the glyphs into one single texture is definitely the best for performance. The reason I took a per-glyph approach in the tutorial is that it's easier to digest for readers new to glyph rendering. If I were to also take the time to describe how to pack the glyphs and render each glyph differently with different UV coordinates the tutorial would be massive and more difficult to understand. The tutorial has a note about this at the end and suggests readers to work this out themselves.

Comment: @JoeyDewd: I understand and appreciate the difficult balancing act of deciding what to teach and what not to. However, texture atlases are a basic and *vital* graphics developer skill. They are used all throughout graphics for various things, but for new graphics programmers, most uses are contrivances. You're not rendering a scene complex enough for the performance difference to be clear. By contrast, text rendering offers the *perfect* opportunity to introduce the concept of a texture atlas. I still say that it does a disservice to your readers to not introduce it here.

Comment: I agree, Ideally I'd have 3 seperate tutorials: one for texture atlasses, one for FreeType and one for generating texture atlasses with FreeType in that order (and optionally one for signed distance field rendering). I've noted it all down on my to-do list.

Comment: Thank you! Joey for introducing me to freetype in opengl and Nicol for giving me the way to follow. I would like to avoid "learning by doing" but tutorials are available so easily...and it is not easy to sort out which theoretical background is the most suitable. I have now used textures atlas and it works , at least for it self.

Answer (score 2):

I found another tutorial in two parts, the first part (very similar pedagogically to Joey's tutorial) calling gldraw  for each glyph and the second part explaining how to draw a whole string in one call. Here is the link to the second part. It is possible to download the complete code (scroll down the page). Thank you!

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02

Comment: Just to clarify for those coming to this now, this is the tutorial that talks about **texture atlases**. This is the one to follow. Thanks Jonathan.